# Why syncolor.vim is sourced at the end of cygwin vim started and replaced the specifed colorscheme

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, cygwin

To make the usage of vim in cygwin convenient, I've added the color scheme in [my cygwin .vimrc](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc_cygwin). But I found the color scheme doesn't work when vim is started.

So I did some investigations:

1. My Cygwin indeed support `xterm-256color`. [This is 256 color test script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/incitat/eran-dotfiles/master/bin/terminalcolors.py):
   [image: xterm]
   [image: xterm2]
2. The Comment highlight style indeed setup in [the .vimrc](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc_cygwin#L110):
   `hi Comment ctermfg=239`
3. But the final Comment color scheme was loaded from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim`
   [image: vim-verbose]
4. My .vimrc was indeed sourced, but the color part was replaced by syncolor.vim. Because syncolor.vim is sourced twice, and it's sourced at the end of vim startup. I'm using the `# vim -u ~/.cygwin/.vimrc --startuptime startup.log` to check the startup scripts as below:

```
    times in msec
     clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
     clock   elapsed:              other lines

    000.003  000.003: --- VIM STARTING ---
    000.076  000.073: Allocated generic buffers
    000.124  000.048: locale set
    000.127  000.003: clipboard setup
    000.130  000.003: window checked
    007.568  007.438: inits 1
    007.576  000.008: parsing arguments
    007.577  000.001: expanding arguments
    007.623  000.046: shell init
    008.543  000.920: Termcap init
    008.562  000.019: inits 2
    008.791  000.229: init highlight
    016.569  001.641  001.641: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
    017.190  003.695  002.054: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
    043.658  024.373  024.373: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
    044.007  032.170  004.102: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
    045.527  000.074  000.074: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
    047.319  000.182  000.182: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
    049.047  000.151  000.151: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
    049.926  039.919  007.342: sourcing /cygdrive/c/Users/310258281/.cygwin/.vimrc
    049.947  001.237: sourcing vimrc file(s)
    053.216  001.338  001.338: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/fzf.vim
    058.199  000.224  000.224: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
    060.159  000.664  000.664: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
    061.716  000.449  000.449: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
    062.920  000.166  000.166: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/manpager.vim
    064.748  000.545  000.545: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
    067.242  001.156  001.156: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
    068.456  000.122  000.122: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
    069.628  000.137  000.137: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
    071.121  000.530  000.530: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
    072.821  000.264  000.264: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
    074.253  000.478  000.478: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
    075.695  000.465  000.465: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
    075.716  019.231: loading plugins
    077.403  001.687: loading packages
    077.839  000.436: loading after plugins
    077.851  000.012: inits 3
    078.628  000.777: reading viminfo
    078.634  000.006: setting raw mode
    078.652  000.018: start termcap
    078.724  000.072: clearing screen
    090.187  011.463: opening buffers
    090.254  000.067: BufEnter autocommands
    090.263  000.009: editing files in windows
    092.323  000.474  000.474: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
    094.458  003.721: VimEnter autocommands
    094.464  000.006: before starting main loop
    094.627  000.163: first screen update
    094.630  000.003: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

So simply speaking, vim works as below:

```
 016.569  001.641  001.641: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
 049.926  039.919  007.342: sourcing /cygdrive/c/Users/310258281/.cygwin/.vimrc
 092.323  000.474  000.474: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

Why's that?

Oh, by the way, my environment:

- OS: Win10 64bit
- Cygwin: mintty 2.6.2 (x86-64-pc-cygwin)
- Vim in Cygwin: version 7.4.2367,  Modified by

Comment: It looks like you have some VimEnter autocommands there. I wonder what they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simpler workaround.  Just add `let g:syntax_cmd = "skip"` to your .vimrc.

From [`:h syntax_cmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax_cmd):

```
The "syntax_cmd" variable is set to one of these values when the
syntax/syncolor.vim files are loaded:
   "on"     ":syntax on" command.  Highlight colors are overruled but
        links are kept
   "enable" ":syntax enable" command.  Only define colors for groups that
        don't have highlighting yet.  Use ":syntax default".
   "reset"  ":syntax reset" command or loading a color scheme.  Define all
        the colors.
   "skip"   Don't define colors.  Used to skip the default settings when a
        syncolor.vim file earlier in 'runtimepath' has already set
        them.
```

syncolors.vim checks if syntax_cmd is set.  If it's set to "skip", it exits without changing any of your settings.

Comment: Thanks @Ray very much!! This is the perfect solution!!! I'm using the `let syntax_cmd = "enable"` in my .vimrc, I want colors defined by myself shows the color which it defined. And the groups shows default which I haven't been defineded.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Okay, I found the reason. There's code shows in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim`:
[image: vim2]

$ cat -n /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim

```
...
    17  " Set the default highlighting colors.  Use a color scheme if specified.
    18  if exists("colors_name")
    19    exe "colors " . colors_name
    20  else
    21    runtime! syntax/syncolor.vim
    22  endif
...
```

Which means, if there's no colorcheme defined in vimrc, so the syncolor.vim will be the default one.... No wonder the syncolor.vim are loaded twice.

So, a simple workaround, add `colorscheme xxx` in the vimrc, it will prevent syncolor.vim re-load, and also my colorscheme will replace the color name set in vimrc:
[image: vim3]

Comment: Why don't you move your `highlight` commands to a proper colorscheme?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin and Gitbash at the same time. If I'm using the colorscheme, then this file has to be copy to both git and cygwin folders, which means, if I want to change anything in git colorscheme file, then I have to sync change to cygwin vim colorscheme file again. 
If the colorscheme file set in ~/.vim, my windows gvim will get impacted.

I'm using the gvim.exe most of time, I don't want to wast many times to mantain vimrc in cygwin/git bash

Comment: synload.vim sources syncolor.vim the first time. I doubt it's responsible for the second one.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the information you've supplied, by the way.

Comment: @Antony are you using cygwin?